# ROS Autopilot possibility?

Tags: ros, mavlink

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I' not much of a software guy but, I wonder if it is possible to create an autopilot node that can connect to Qcontrol via Mavlink. The point of this is basically to create cheap affordable UAVs with computer vision.

Thanks for your help!!! :D

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12500/ros-autopilot-possibility?/) by [Just Asking](https://answers.ros.org/users/1597/just-asking/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-01-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There already seems to be a package [Mavlink](http://www.ros.org/wiki/mavlink-ros-pkg) in ROS.  A quick browse of the [repository](http://https://github.com/pixhawk/mavlink-ros-pkg) seems to show the software is being developed.

---

Originally posted by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) with karma: 586 on 2012-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Just Asking](https://answers.ros.org/users/1597/just-asking/) on 2012-01-06**:
Yes. Basically I like to try and develop a cheap autopilot running ROS with computer vision. The computer vision comes with only the PixHawk IMU. I'm trying to create a cheaper alternative. The problem is that I'm not too much of a software guy to know what to do.

**Comment by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on 2012-01-04**:
Are you looking for a drop in replacement for the pixhawk IMU board?

**Comment by [Just Asking](https://answers.ros.org/users/1597/just-asking/) on 2012-01-03**:
The question though is will this package work with any computer system. The PixHawk project I find uses rather specific (and rather and expensive and mind boggling) system. Thank you very much though.